# debugging elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using tire and elasticsearch. The service has started using port 9200. However, it was returning 2 errors:

```
"org.elasticsearch.search.SearchParseException: [countries][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"name:"}}}]]"
```

and

```
"Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'name:': Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 5."
```

So, I reinstalled elasticsearch and the service container. Service starts fine.

Now, when I search using tire I get no results when results should appear *and* I don't receive *any* error messages.

Does anybody have any idea how I might find out what is wrong, let alone fix it?

Comment: Did you reindex the data after reinstalling ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

first of all, **you don't need to reindex anything**, in the usual cases. It depends how you installed and configured *elasticsearch*, but when you install and upgrade eg. with [*Homebrew*](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/elasticsearch.rb), the data are persisted safely.

Second, **no need to reinstall** anything. The error you're seeing means just what it says on the tin: `SearchParseException`, ie. your query is invalid:

```
{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"name:"}}}
```

Notice that you didn't pass any query string for the name qualifier. You have to pass something, eg:

```
{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"name:foo"}}}
```

or, in Ruby terms:

```
Tire.index('test') { query { string "name:hey" } }
```

See [this update to the Railscasts episode on Tire](https://github.com/karmi/railscasts-episodes/commit/a2e45741d7e2ed82dffc88b6e2512655106f35a7) for an example how to catch errors due to incorrect Lucene queries.